# How to convert hierarchical Pages to hierarchical Custom Post Types? Slugs get a number as if they were duplicates

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical

I have an existing WP installation with 300 Pages, hierarchically structured. Editors intend to create around 2000 of them. Over time it becomes hard to find a particular page with the wordpress search function in the admin panel and it is hard to select a parent since there are many items in the dropdown.

I want to introduce CPTs to make the pages easier to manage.

What is the correct way to do this?

---

What I have tried:

1. I installed the [Post Type Switcher plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/). Whenever I convert a page to CPT & click "save", Wordpress is appending a number in the slug, as if there was a duplicate. For example, `/holiday/usa/` becomes `/holiday/usa-2/`. Refreshing the permalink structure didn't help.
2. I tried manually converting the post_type with SQL. Still the same problem, permalinks get a number at the end.

---

How my CPT code looks like:

```
$args = array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'public' => true, 
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'menu_position'       => 4,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'query_var'           => 'holiday',
    'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'holiday',
        'with_front' => true, 
        'pages'      => true,
        'feeds'      => true,
        'ep_mask'    => EP_PERMALINK
    ),
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'author',
        'thumbnail',
        'revisions',
        'page-attributes'
    )
);

register_post_type(
    'holiday',
    $args
);
```

Comment: Try adding `pre_wp_unique_post_slug` filter before conversion. If your filter returns passed `$slug` value, it should stop WordPress from trying to create new unique slug. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_wp_unique_post_slug/

Comment: @VitautsStočka So that would practically overwrite the slug duplication mechanism in WP, right? I can say something like `if (post_type == 'my_custom_type') return $slug; else return null;` in the filter function, do I understand you correctly?